# At/ on the point of leaving

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

I came across this:

> The phone rang when Tom was on the point of leaving.

As I usually use "**at** the point of leaving", are both possible?

Comment: Use "at". When I read "on", I think "Tom was (on the brink of) leaving."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *on*, personally.

[Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20point%20of%20leaving%2C%20at%20the%20point%20of%20leaving&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20point%20of%20leaving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20point%20of%20leaving%3B%2Cc0) suggests that both are possible, but that *on* is the more common of the two:

[image: the point of leaving]

If I look at some of the actual examples of the *at* phrasing gathered by Google, it seems that it's sometimes used in a more literal sense [(*the banks of the bayou at the point of leaving the river*)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aIJpAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA469&dq=%22at%20the%20point%20of%20leaving%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMgauG4uffAhXstlkKHSvSAYIQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22at%20the%20point%20of%20leaving%22&f=false), even though I see examples of its figurative use too.

So, both can be used. It's up to you to decide which you prefer.